# Spring JPA specification convert root type to compare successfully

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So my `File` *created* date is a timestamp in `OffsetDateTime`, and API's request param comes in as `LocalDate` without any time. I would need to compare them as equal if the date is the same, drop out the time from the equation.

I though of doing something like this, but it is not working properly. Even with the `<LocalDate>`.

```
private Specification<File> isOfInitiationDate(LocalDate initiationDate) {
    return (Specification<File>) (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<LocalDate>get("created"), initiationDate);
}
```

I receive:

```
Parameter value [2021-02-03] did not match expected type [java.time.OffsetDateTime (n/a)]
```

How could I make this Specification return values in case of the `root.get("created)` date would be the same as `LocalDate initiationDate`?

Comment: can you evaluate the expression get("created") in your IDE during debug? see what concrete type is returned and cast it accordingly.

Comment: @TomElias checked, it is `OffsetDateTime`, how do you suggest I should cast it and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem on my own. I casted it like this:

`root.get("created).as(LocalDate.class)`

Now it compares both variables as a `LocalDate` and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

convert OffsetDateTime to localdate as per below, sample code as below

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime=get("created");
Localdate localDate=offsetDateTime.toLocaldate();

criteriaBuilder.equal(localDate, initiationDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I managed to fix it by doing it like this `root.get("created).as(LocalDate.class)`, now everything works fine!